# Error: 0x80041001 when running VBScript to enumerate software

Tags: windows, vbscript

When I ran a VBScript on a windows8.1 machine, I got the following error.  Same code ran successfully on other machines.

```
Error: 0x80041001
Code: 80041001
Source: (null)
The error line is 'For each ...'
```

Code:

```
'obtain collection of Windows Installer packages

Set MSIapps = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & Computer & "\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Product where Name like 'Cisco%'")

'enumerate the names of the packages in the collection

For each App in MSIapps 

    version =  App.Version
    installDIR = App.InstallLocation


Next
```

Comment: How defined the `Computer` variable?

Comment: Yes, I did.   Const Computer = "."

Answer (score 0):

In theory, by [Starting and Stopping the WMI Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826517(v=vs.85).aspx):

> WMI runs as a service with the display name "Windows Management
>   Instrumentation" and the service name "winmgmt". WMI runs
>   automatically at system startup under the LocalSystem account. If WMI
>   is not running, it automatically starts when the first management
>   application or script requests connection to a WMI namespace.

Looks like your `winmgmt` service has stopped working for some reason. At a command prompt (run as administrator), enter `net start winmgmt` and watch output message.

Configure the service to run automatically with `services.msc` or follow e.g. *Chang Yin's* answer to [WMI corrupt - how to reinstall/repair?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8/wmi-corrupt-how-to-reinstallrepair).

Comment: Thanks, looks like the WMI corrupt on that computer.