# Using WMI to search in MicrosoftDNS_AType records cause generic failure

Tags: c#, dns, wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service

All day long trying to fix 0x80041001 error, but it's still shows that error. Turning firewall off, UAC off, didn't work. reseting WMI service, trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384094/6363853), Running as administrator, still nothing changed! It's my code:

```
ManagementScope mgmtScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\Root\MicrosoftDNS", new ConnectionOptions() {  });
ManagementObjectCollection mgmtDNSRecords = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgmtScope, new ObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_AType WHERE OwnerName = '{0}.{1}'", strHostName, strDNSZone))).Get();
// Here the error accours:
if (mgmtDNSRecords.Count > 1)
```

Event viewer Error:

> Id = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}; ClientMachine =
>   ARASHSERVER; User = ARASHSERVER\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 1004;
>   Component = Unknown; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery -
>   Root\MicrosoftDNS : SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_AType; ResultCode =
>   0x80041001; PossibleCause = Unknown

Running wbemtest.exe shows this error:

> DNS_ERROR_ZONE_DOES_NOT_EXIST

Is there any fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_Zone
```

resulted a list that one zone was missing, I mean there were a zone in DNS manager (with no records) but didn't listed in query result. I deleted that zone and magically, problem solved!